# Threads: Timeout lock

Tags: c, multithreading, timeout, pthreads

Program description:

I wrote a demo for conditional waiting. The program starts two threads and then waits for both to finish. One of the threads reads user-pressed keys from the keyboard, and if the `q` key is pressed, sets a condition variable, after that the thread ends.

How can I implement the second thread to run in an infinite loop a sequence in which it waits for the condition variable for up to 1 second, and if the set variable appears then it exits the infinite loop, and if it does not appear and expires in 1 second, it displays a `*` on the console and returns to standby?

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>


pthread_mutex_t m=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t c=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *fun1()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    while (1)
    {
        char ch;
        scanf("%c",&ch);
        if(ch=='q')
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
            pthread_cond_signal(&c);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
    }

}

void *fun2()
{
    struct timespec to;
    pthread_condattr_t attr;
     pthread_condattr_init( &attr);
    pthread_condattr_setclock( &attr, CLOCK_MONOTONIC);
    pthread_cond_init( &c, &attr);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &to);
    to.tv_sec += 1;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("hello world\n");
        int rc=pthread_cond_timedwait(&c,&m,&to);
        printf("%d",rc==ETIMEDOUT);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
        // if(rc==ETIMEDOUT)
        // {

        // }

        //     pthread_exit(NULL);

    }

}

int main()
{
    pthread_t id[2];
    pthread_mutex_init(&m,NULL);
    pthread_cond_init( &c, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    pthread_create(&id[0],NULL,fun1,NULL);

    pthread_create(&id[1],NULL,fun2,NULL);
    pthread_join(id[0],NULL);
    pthread_join(id[1],NULL);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: <O/T> no need to do `pthread_mutex_init` and `pthread_cond_init` since you're using the static initializers.

Comment: I guess the better question is this: what is the mutex *protecting* in `fun1` ? Also. pthread function have a specific calling signature. `void (*)(void*);` Neither of your functions match that.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the code looks at-best to be pure-guesswork. Pthread mutex and condition variable pairing has specific rolls and responsibilities.

- The mutex protects some external 'predicate' data
- The condition variable signals a change to 'predicate' data.

The management of both the mutex and the condition variable is *completely* wrong.

- repeated initialization of the already-initialized objects.
- acquiring, and *never* releasing the mutex in `fun1`
- both functions have the wrong signature for proper pthread threads.
- neither function provides state return values

Related, some pthread implementations do not support clock-selection. In those cases, even fixing the code, the condition variable cannot be configured for monotonic clock selection; realtime is the only alternative.

Fixing everything above,

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t c = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
bool quit = false;

void *fun1(void *pv)
{
    while (1)
    {
        char ch;
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        if (ch == 'q')
        {
            // latch mutex before changing predicate
            pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
            quit = true;
            pthread_cond_signal(&c);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
            break;
        }
    }

    return pv;
}

void *fun2(void *pv)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    while (1)
    {
        printf("hello world\n");

        struct timespec to;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &to);
        to.tv_sec += 1;
        int rc = pthread_cond_timedwait(&c, &m, &to); 
        if (rc != ETIMEDOUT || quit == true)
            break;
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    return pv;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t id[2];

    pthread_create(id+0, NULL, fun1, NULL);
    pthread_create(id+1, NULL, fun2, NULL);

    pthread_join(id[0], NULL);
    pthread_join(id[1], NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Pay close attention to how the mutex protects the predicate data (`quit`), and how that data is *never* checked, nor modified, without protection from that mutex by *any* thread. It's important.

Finally, note that `fun1` (or `fun2` ; pick one) is ultimately pointless in this code. Starting threads and waiting for them *all* to finish as the sole responsibility of `main` is a code smell that something can be done in `main` to avoid at least one of those threads. For example:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t c = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
bool quit = false;

void *fun2(void *pv)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    while (1)
    {
        printf("hello world\n");

        struct timespec to;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &to);
        to.tv_sec += 1;
        int rc = pthread_cond_timedwait(&c, &m, &to);
        if (rc != ETIMEDOUT || quit == true)
            break;
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    return pv;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t id;

    pthread_create(&id, NULL, fun2, NULL);

    while (1)
    {
        char ch;
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        if (ch == 'q')
        {
            // latch mutex before changing predicate
            pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
            quit = true;
            pthread_cond_signal(&c);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
            break;
        }
    }

    pthread_join(id, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Does *exactly* the same thing as the previous code, but uses `main` as the driver for what `fun1` was originally doing. Always consider this as an option worth pursuing if you can. Be kind to your scheduler; it will return the favor someday.